# Listando dados separando-os por data

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero listar todos os produtos separados por data. Tipo, produtos da data tal ficam em uma tabela, já de outra data fica em outra tabela, e por aí vai... Tudo isso na mesma página.

Comment: Primeiro você pode selecionar usando GROUP BY data, e depois monta um novo select para pegar os produtos somente daquela data... exibindo assim: DATA X ---- produtos | DATA Y ---- produtos

Answer (score 1):

A forma a seguir tenta minimizar o número de consultas ao banco de dados, ficando apenas duas consultas e para o resto o PHP fica responsável.

A lógica nada mais é que obter as datas que serão listadas ordenadas, e obter a lista de todos os produtos ordenados pelas datas também. Em seguida percorre a a lista de datas, e para cada data vc percorre a lista de produtos removendo cada item depois de apresentar, até a data mudar. Quando mudar a tabela é finalizada e passa para a próxima data.

```
<?php
// Obtendo as compras ordenadas pela data
$sqlCompras = '
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(c.`data`, '%d-%m-Y') as "data",
        c.`produtoNome`,
        c.`preco`
    FROM `compras` as c
    ORDER BY
        DATE_FORMAT(c.`data`, '%d-%m-Y') ASC,
        c.`produtoNome` ASC
';
$resCompras = $conexao->prepare($sqlCompras);
$resCompras->execute();
$compras = $resCompras->fetchAll();

// Obtendo todas as datas disponíveis
$sqlDatas = '
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(c.`data`, '%d-%m-Y') as "data"
    FROM `compras` as c
    GROUP BY BY c.`data`
    ORDER BY
        DATE_FORMAT(c.`data`, '%d-%m-Y') ASC,
';
$resDatas = $conexao->prepare($sqlDatas);
$resDatas->execute();
$datas = $resDatas->fetchAll();
?>

<?php foreach ($datas as $data) { ?>
<table>
    <caption><?php echo $data['data'] ?></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nome do produto</th>
            <th scope="col">Preço</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($compras as $key => $compra) { ?>
            <?php
            // Percorre os produtos até encontrar uma data diferente,
            // quando encontrar, quebra o laço de repetição e passa para a
            // próxima data.
            if( $compra['data'] != $data['data']) {
                break;
            } else {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $compra['produtoNome'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $compra['preco'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php unset($compras[$key]) ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```